# Linq - select distinct values

Tags: linq, distinct

I have the following object in a collection (List)

```
public class MyObject{

    string vendor;
    string unit;

    int unit123;
    AnotherObject unit456;
}
```

This can be long and repetitive.

I want to select, using linq,  only the distinct values of vendor and unit and put it in the following structure

Dictionary

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain the Key and Value of your dictionary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
List<MyObject> l = new List<MyObject>();
//fill the list

Dictioonary<string,string> d = 
l
.Select
(
    x=>new
    {
        x.vendor,
        x.unit
    }
) //Get only the properties you care about.
.Distinct()
.ToDictionary
(
    x=>x.vendor,  //Key selector
    x=>x.unit     //Value selector
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Improved my question by adding more fields (not to be used in the distinct)

Comment: What if there are some duplicate vendor after distinct, it would break dictionary

Comment: @CuongLe Then there must be more info on what to do with unit. We could change it to GroupBy, but then we would need to know how to handle units. But until otherwise noted the solution stands.